# CSV-backed ORM?

Tags: ruby, csv, orm, data-analysis

I'm looking for an ORM that supports CSV as the data-store and that mimics (not too fancy, but some sugar is welcome) ORMs like Sequel, DataMapper or ActiveRecord.

My goal is to import some CSV datasets and query them, do some basic aggregation, etc.

It should be something similar to http://pandas.pydata.org/ in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

CSV files will have horrible performance for that. CSV files and records are not meant for random access, because text files are not. You can't update a field in CSV without it affecting all other fields and records following it. As the file changes size because a record changes, your code will suffer major slowdowns as the entire file is rewritten. Are you *REALLY* sure that is the way you want to go?

Instead, I'd use an in-memory SQLite database if it'll fit, or one on disk, read the CSV into it, do all the changes there, then write the CSV back out. You'll notice in the Panda docs they hint that they're doing something similar:

> Tools for reading and writing data between in-memory data structures and different formats....

It'd be a trivial task to do this with the [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class and the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) gem.

Comment: that's for data analysis. I would like to have something like R dataframes.. so the "slowdowns" cited aren't a problem (i mean, it shouldn't be a problem for a single user analysis)

Comment: The issue is the I/O will grow slower and slower as the file gets bigger, and it will scale very badly.